# How to pass a numpy array of string types to a function in Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Passing a numpy array of dtype `np.float64_t` works fine ( below), but I can't pass string arrays.

**This is what works :**

```
# cython_testing.pyx
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.float64_t dtype_t 

cdef func1 (np.ndarray[dtype_t, ndim=2] A):
    print A 

def testing():
    chunk = np.array ( [[94.,3.],[44.,4.]], dtype=np.float64)

    func1 (chunk)
```

**But I can't make this work:**
I can't find the matching 'type identifiers' for numpy string dtypes.

```
# cython_testing.pyx
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

ctypedef np.string_t dtype_str_t 

cdef func1 (np.ndarray[dtype_str_t, ndim=2] A):
    print A 

def testing():
    chunk = np.array ( [['huh','yea'],['swell','ray']], dtype=np.string_)

    func1 (chunk)
```

**The compilation error is :**

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
ctypedef np.string_t dtype_str_t 
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

cython_testing.pyx:9:9: 'string_t' is not a type identifier
```

**UPDATE**

Per looking through `numpy.pxd`, I see the following `ctypedef` statements. Maybe that's enough to say I can use `uint8_t` and pretend everything is normal, as long as I can do some casting?

```
ctypedef unsigned char      npy_uint8
ctypedef npy_uint8      uint8_t
```

Just have to see how expensive that casting will be.

Answer (score 9):

With Cython 0.20.1 it works using `cdef np.ndarray`, without specifying the data type and the number of dimensions:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef func1(np.ndarray A):
    print A

def testing():
    chunk = np.array([['huh','yea'], ['swell','ray']])
    func1(chunk)
```

Comment: @TedPetrou I am trying to build an example where the `dtype=object` would accelerate in order to update the answer, but up to now I found it to be equivalent to not specifying `dtype`. How did you measure the 100x speed up?

Comment: Looks like I massively misspoke in my previous comment. It looks like I am getting 5x improvement by changing to object. Use this array. `a = np.array(['some', 'strings', 'in', 'an', 'array'] * 10 ** 5)`

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you're out of luck.

http://cython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html

> Some data types are not yet supported, like boolean arrays and string arrays.

---

This answer is no longer valid as shown by Saullo Castro's answer, but I'll leave it for historical purposes.

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted your answer. Though I hope there is a work around by using perhaps the Numpy Structured array [http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#structured-arrays]. But I am still looking for how to pass one of those too.

Comment: At least for my purposes, using cProfile, it looks like you can still pass Numpy arrays w/o typing, in Cython. But you do not get the Cython optimizations described in your readthedocs.org reference.

Comment: Being able to use them slowly is still better than not being able to use them at all, though, right?

Comment: Content of this link has been modified. The quote doesn't exist.