# str object and string dtypes mismatch in Cython

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, cython

I'm trying to run a simple `Cython` code with **ipython** notebook. I have the following code snippet:

```
%load_ext cythonmagic
%%cython
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef int test(np.ndarray[np.str, ndim = 1] a):
    return 6

print test(np.array(['gona','haraka']))
```

What I want is to pass a numpy 1D array of strings into the function. When the function `test` is executed, it returns 0 and I get the following error:

> Exception ValueError: "Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'str object'
>   but got a string" in
>   '_cython_magic_505ff8c1b7497cde585006f723e794bd.test' ignored

What can be the reason for this?
How do I pass a numpy array of strings?
Even if I use `str` instead of `np.str` or give `dtype=np.str` in the numpy array when the function `test` is called, I get the same error.

Comment: If you downvote this question, please provide a reason as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a numpy array of string types to a function in Cython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003037/how-to-pass-a-numpy-array-of-string-types-to-a-function-in-cython)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested  with Cython 0.20.1 and you can just use a general `np.ndarray` definition, not specifying the data type or the number of dimensions:

```
cimport cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef int test(np.ndarray a):
    return 6

print test(np.array(['gona', 'haraka']))
```

If you want a better performance you can pass the NumPy string array using only its pointer and passing the array around through a `char *` buffer. The following example shows how this can be achieved. It increases the character code adding 1 to each non-zero value:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef int f(char *a, int size):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(size):
        if a[i]!=0:
            a[i] += 1

def main():
    cdef char *inp
    cdef np.ndarray a
    a = np.array(['aaaa', 'bbbbbb'])
    inp = a.data
    print a
    f(inp, a.itemsize*a.shape[0])
    print a
```

When you run `main()` you get:

```
['aaaa' 'bbbbbb']
['bbbb' 'cccccc']
```

Comment: np.ndarray without specifying the dtype works fine. But I couldn't test the latter way.

Comment: @maheshakya the latter way might be more relevant if you would pass this array to some `C` function with `char *` as one of the inputs...